# Output loop result into a list

Tags: python

Someone please help me with this code:

```
agerlist = for agern in anime.info['Genres']:
      print agern['name']
```

Is there any way to save the output into one variable? An example would be: `alist = agern in anime.info` ?

Comment: [`agerlist = [agern['name'] for agern in anime.info['Genres']]`?](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
alist = [ x['name'] for x in anime.info['Genre']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty list and then append the results of for loop to that list or you could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
l = []
for agern in anime.info['Genres']:
    l.append(agern['name'])
print l
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also store that into a generator function, something like this:

```
for agern in anime.info['Genres']:
    yield agern['name']
```

so that you will actually compute this thing only on request, i.e. during a for cycle, so you will not store in memory each agern['name'] two times.